# Why use 交货 in 我们可不可以把有些数量提前到三月交货？

Tags: usage

> 我们可不可以把有些数量提前到三月交货

Why do we use 交货 here? Can we do without it?

Comment: w/o 交货, to deliver goods, the sentence would be incomplete and violate the rules for 把 sentences 有些数量 is the object of the verb 交货,提前 (ahead of time), 到三月 (by March) can be considered adverbial adjuncts, in fact the construction 把某事交货 for "deliver sth." seems unusual

Comment: Agreed. If you were discussing a plan/schedule with someone who knows the plan. Addition of 交貨 would mean, to me, more focus onto having the goods shipped out to customers.

Comment: maybe unusual, but grammatical,cf.＂实用现代汉语语法＂：＂把＂字句 一、。。。 有时＂把＂的宾语是谓语动词的施事，既动作的发出者，大多有＂使＂、＂让＂的意义。（此类＂把＂字句有的表示不如意情况）。例如：１。她真不幸，跟丈夫离婚不久，又把个孩子死了。（孩子死）２。怎么把特务跑了？（特务跑）.把有些数量提前到三月交货 thus seems equivalent to 使有些数量提前到三月交货

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this part of your sentence with 交货 (t: 交貨) omitted, its spot represented by the `___` below, this would be what it looks like, loosely translated:

```
subject:           predicate:
... some amounts   be rescheduled earlier for March ___
```

There are some terms or concepts in language that, although are not verbs themselves, have a commonly associated course of action understood by everybody. Only in such cases, it is possible a further specific verb, course of action `___` can be omitted. However,

`Amounts`:

- is *not* normally understood as some kind of verb or some kind of action, for which you can then associate with a schedule clause
- in this case, with no further context, there is no single "obvious" course of action to relate to `amounts`. For example `amounts` if talking about some physical goods or material resource, depending on what kind of goods or material resource, can have associated actions such as extraction, refinement, disposal, audit, inventory (taking), and yes, also delivery. Without further context there is no evidence that "delivery" is the correct interpretation

Example, omit action:

[image: Animated image of a belly dancer belly dancing]

```
subject:               predicate
... the belly dancer   be rescheduled earlier for 7PM ___
```

- As in `Can the belly dancer be rescheduled earlier for 7PM ?`
- it is commonly understood that a belly dancer belly dances, that is a commonly associated course of action understood by everybody
- thus you do not need the additional `___` to clarify `for 7PM belly dancing`
- you would normally only specify the `___` action clarification, if the belly dancer were to do something other than the expected belly dancing

However in your posted example, without further context, since `amounts` does not necessarily have a commonly associated course of action `delivery`, of course you need to clarify and specify which of the possible action of `amounts` you intend to reschedule.

Image credit: http://www.picgifs.com/graphics/belly-dancing/graphics-belly-dancing-471150-794732/

Comment: Can you deliver the belly-dancer to Taiwan before Christmas?